# How to create helper functions in a flex application

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, singleton, helper

I have a flex application, and I am using a cairngorm structure -

src/com/mysite/editor/model/ contains the following two things

EditorModelLocator.as (Singleton Enforced Application Globals),
EditorGlobalConstants.as (Contains All constants), like the following

```
public static const SUPPORT_PHONE:String = '800-865-7496';
public static const SUPPORT_EMAIL:String = 'support@mysite.com';
```

I was wondering where the best place to put helper methods is. I need these to be methods I can use outside of the singleton enforced class. Would it make sense to put it in Global Constants? The only thing against that, is I always use EditorGlobalConstants the same way:

```
EditorGlobalConstants.SUPPORT_PHONE
```

An example of a 'helper function' is the following:

```
public var blank(value:String):Boolean {
  if( value == '' || value == null ) return true;
  return false;
}
```

I can store all of this information in EditorGlobalConstants, but I was wondering if maybe EditorHelpers.as would be better, and how I would instantiate/use that solution?

Thanks!

Andrew Thorp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to use your helper methods not only in your singleton class, it would be better to place them somewhere upper in hierarchy. You can easily find that place by yourself. Let's try:

1. Break up your application (in imagination/paper/whatever) into a boxes. Each class is a separate box.
2. Put them into structure. You just need to see, which boxes are placed inside which ones.
3. Mark the boxes-classes, where are you going to use these methods.
4. Find the top level, where are you going to use them and place your class there.

Let's see an example .. suppose you have this structure:

```
ToplevelApplication
|-BoxAtLevel_1
| |-BoxAtLevel_2
...
```

if I want my helpers used only in BoxAtLevel_2, I'd put them there:

```
|-BoxAtLevel_1
| |-BoxAtLevel_2
| |-Helpers
```

And so on .. if you have any troubles - put your structure here, and I'll help.

Also, about EditorHelpers.as .. is this an instance-level things or rather class-level ones? That's what going to set the way you'll use them.

Comment: Well, that's sort of my question.. This is a flex application, and EditorModelLocator, EditorGlobalConstants, and EditorHelpers need to be accessible at any point in the application. This is why I decided to create a separate class EditorHelpers.as. Would it make sense to create these methods as static methods so I don't have to instantiate the EditorHelpers in order to use them?

Comment: if so, yes. If you're going to use methods widely in your application, they're just asking to promote them as static :) Just one more question:  Have you considered placing those functions into e.g. a base class? (Cause if your functions relate to your classes, placing them at the global level would break the encapsulation principles).

Answer (score 1):

Not familiar with how cairngorm tends to do things, but in AS3 functions don't have to be part of a class.

For instance, you could have a file called `helperFunction.as` with the contents:

```
package my.package {
  public function helperFunction(arg1:Object, arg2:String):void {
    // Do stuff
  }
}
```

Then just import that method like you would anything else:

```
import my.package.helperFunction
```

and you can use it in your code.

Just pick a package that would make sense for the method to live in (probably in the same package that the objects it's meant to help with are defined).